# ASP.NET (C#) Column Chart on top of Column Chart

Tags: c#, asp.net, graph, overlapping

I am drawing 2 RangeColumn Graphs, problem is they appear next to each other.  I am wondering if there is a setting that will allow me to draw the graphs on top of each other.  So graph 2 will be visible over graph 1.  Both graphs have different widths so I should still be able to see graph 1 in the back.

Here is a google image I found that describes what I want

[image]

Comment: So you are making a Candlestick/OHLC type graph? What graph technology/framework are you using?

Comment: I am using ASP.NET Charts and using c# to set it up.  I am just trying to figure out how to program 2 RangeColumn Graphs to overlap each other as they are in the image above.  That image is a random image from google that shows what I am trying to graph.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456710.aspx

You need to set the DrawSideBySide property to false. You can then play with the widths to get your desired effect.

Comment: THANK YOU!  I can't tell you how long I've been researching to find this feature.  thank you!!!  Just for clarification for those who want to achieve the same effect.  Here is the example code I ran: Chart1.Series[0]["DrawSideBySide"] = "false";
        Chart1.Series[1]["DrawSideBySide"] = "false";  -  So I ran it for both series to make it work.

Comment: No worries, glad you found what you was looking for.